# In JFrog Artifactory can we customize artifacts folders in the virtual repository

Tags: artifactory

See for example I have local repository with some artifacts inside a folder "TEST", I have created a virtual repository and included the above local repository, can I rename "TEST" folder inside virtual repository?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you would like to change the folder 'TEST'? Can you elaborate on how you will change the name of the folder 'TEST' in the local repository? If you would like to 'rename' the content of the folder in the same local repository from 'TEST' folder to 'TEST1' folder and you can achieve it by right click on the folder 'TEST' in the local repo, click on 'move' and check the 'Move to a Custom Path', change the path from 'TEST' to 'TEST1' and move the content, in this way you can change the folder name. However, AFAIK you cannot change the folder name in the virtual repository. [Virtual repos](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories) are just a combination of all the repositories inside it.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual Repository is a collection of remote, local and other virtual repositories. read [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories)

The local repo is a pointer in the virtual repo and all changes must be done outside of the virtual repository.

i.e. if you rename the folder in local repository. It will **automatically change** in the virtual repo created by you but not inside the virtual repository.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you cannot. What a virtual repository does is essentially aggregate paths (and for those paths that conflict, it will pick the latest timestampped artifact for you).

So let's say I have local-repo-one/test/myartifact
This is sued by everyone under virtual-repo/test/myartifact

Now there is another team, and they want to download using virtual-repo/newteam/myartifact. What you can do is either copy the artifact to this new path, move it, or copy the artifact to a new local repo under that path. Then add that local the virtual and you'll be able to resolve for newteam/myartifact as at least one repo has this.

What's nice about copying in this scenario is that it uses no extra storage at all. Because of checksum based storage, things are dedupped, so no concerns on that end.

There are also [User Plugins](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Plugins) that can be used to redirect a request, or even a re-write rule in your reverse proxy.